# Root Activity is getting called again and again when coming from background to foreground instead of last activity in stack

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing an hybrid app using IBM worklight where I have to open another webview on the top of existing webview(Cordova webview),so i created a new activity(WebView Activity) to load my external page,but when i am going to background from webview activity by pressing home button and again coming to foreground my MainActivity  getting called and restarts the app,I have used singleTop for my MainActivity in manifest file

```
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
               android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
               android:launchMode="singleTop"
              >
          <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> 
        </intent-filter>  
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.main.sample.NOTIFICATION"/>  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
        </intent-filter>

    </activity> 
    <activity android:name=".WebViewActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
              android:launchMode="singleTop"
              android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">

    </activity>
```

I don't know why it is happening,I want my last activity to get resumed instead of main activity

Answer (score 1):

Read documentation for the modes.This will explain you about what is happening:

> "singleTask" and "singleInstance", should be used only when the > activity has an ACTION_MAIN and a CATEGORY_LAUNCHER filter. > Imagine, for example, what could happen if the filter is missing: An > intent launches a "singleTask" activity, initiating a new task, and > the user spends some time working in that task. The user then presses > the Home button. The task is now sent to the background and is not > visible. Now the user has no way to return to the task, because it is > not represented in the application launcher.

This is one potential solution.There are multiple ways to do this.
Try using the following code in the onCreate method of the activity that is specified as the Launcher Activity in the Manifest:

```
if ((getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) != 0) {
    finish();
    return;
}
```

This will finish your Launcher Activity before it is displayed by detecting that there is already a task running, and your app should instead resume to the last visible Activity.